# calabash-android scroll to element

Tags: android, calabash-android

I am writing some test cases for an android app using calabash-android.

My first idea to find the elements was to just scroll down until the element is found like this:

```
Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into the input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, id|
    q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    while q.empty?
        scroll_down
        q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    end
    enter_text("android.widget.EditText id:'#{id}'", text)
end
```

However should the page change and I already scrolled past the element in this way, I won't find the element i'm searching for. So the second idea was to do the search in this way:

```
Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into the input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, id|
    q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    while q.empty?
        scroll_down
        q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    end
    while q.empty?
        scroll_up
        q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    end
    enter_text("android.widget.EditText id:'#{id}'", text)
end
```

However I don't know how to check for the end of the page and i hope there is a better way to search for the element then to scroll down to the bottom of the page and then scroll up again.

So my two questions are: is there a better option and, if not how, do I find out that I'm at the bottom/top of the page?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the reminder and i pretty much went with your idea jmoody.

I'm going to do it this way:

```
Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into the input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, id|
    q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
    counter = 0
    while q.empty?
        break if counter == 5
        scroll_down
        q = query("EditText id:'#{id}'")
        counter = counter + 1
    end
    if counter == 5
        fail("The button with the id:'#{id}' could not be found")
    else
        enter_text("EditText id:'#{id}'", text)
    end
end
```

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, please do not use an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an example for Calabash Android, but here is an example from Calabash iOS - the concept is the same.  This is not an ideal solution.

- If the page grows, the counter needs to be increased.
- We can't be sure where we started scrolling.  Our tests assume we are always starting from the top.  Maybe you could do the same?

https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app/tree/master/CalWebViewApp/features

---

```
  Scenario: Query UIWebView with css
    Given I am looking at the UIWebView tab
    And I can query for the body with css

  Then(/^I can query for the body with css$/) do
    page(WebViewApp::TabBar).with_active_page do |page|
    qstr = page.query_str("css:'body'")
    visible = lambda {
      query(qstr).count == 1
    }

    counter = 0
    loop do
      break if visible.call || counter == 6
      scroll(page.query_str, :down)
      step_pause
      counter = counter + 1
    end
    res = query(qstr)
    expect(res.count).to be == 1
  end
end
```

If you control the html on the page, you could add hidden elements to mark the top and bottom of the page.

**UPDATE**

I liked Aravin's answer and tried it out in the [CalWebApp](https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app/blob/master/CalWebViewApp/features/steps/tabbar_steps.rb#L10).

```
js = "window.scrollTo(0,0)"
query(tab_name, {calabashStringByEvaluatingJavaScript:js})
wait_for_none_animating
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `javascript` or `jquery` method to perform this action.

#### To scroll to element using jquery

```
evaluate_javascript(query_string, javascript)
```

**Example:**

```
evaluate_javascript('EditText', '#{id}.ScrollTO()')
```

#### To scroll to Top

```
evaluate_javascript('EditText', 'scrollTop()')
```

you can find more details here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/calabash-android/0.5.8/Calabash/Android/Operations:evaluate_javascript